# Prove Identity by Algebraic Manipulations

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-algebra

Question 1:  (A + C)(A' + B)(B + C) = BC

Sol: using left hand side:-

[image: Uncomplete Solution to Question]

Please help me solving it furhter

Comment: Please take the time format your question using MathJax. See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: Shouldn't the 3rd line be B+AB^2+A'BC+B^2C+C+ABC+A'C^2+BC^2=BC?

Comment: @fleablood, It's evidently Boolean Algebra.  (Though, yes, the OP should have specified that.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\rm BC = (A + A')BC = ABC+A'BC$

So from where you left off: $$\begin{align}\rm AB+\color{blue}{BC}+A'C ~=~&\rm BC \\ \rm AB+\color{blue}{ABC+A'BC}+A'C ~=~&\rm BC \\ \vdots~~~&\end{align}$$

---

Or, alternatively

$$\begin{align}\rm AB+BC+A'C ~=~&\rm \color{blue}{BC} \\ \rm AB+BC+A'C~=~&\rm \color{blue}{BC+BC} \\ \rm AB+BC+A'C ~=~&\rm \color{blue}{ABC+A'BC+BC} \\ \vdots~~~&\end{align}$$

Comment: but how the last step can be written as (A + A')BC ? #Graham

Comment: Because $A+A'=1$

Comment: But how AB + BC + A'C = (A+A') BC ? #Graham

Comment: @MuddassirNayyer  Ah, no. You substitute.  I've added a clarification.

Comment: Sorry #Graham I am still unable to understand. Please give me the full solution